# I live in Brazil, I have no US bank account and received a US Treasury check. How do I get my money?

Tags: united-states, irs, working-abroad, check

I'm an US citizen living abroad who has no US bank account and that got a tax refund from the IRS.

I have and frequently use a Paypal account, but Paypal accounts for people living outside the US do no accept US-checks deposit.

My only bank account is on a Brazilian bank.

Do any of you guys know how can I make that check into money?

Answer (score 6):

Deposit it into your Brazilian bank account. They'll charge you collection fee (shouldn't be high, its a cashier's check equivalent), and the currency exchange rate may not be the best ever, but that's the price to pay for the service.

Another option would be to cash the check at check cashing places, but that would most likely require you being in the US (I don't know if any check-cashing store in Brazil would cash a US check).

Answer (score 0):

Go to a Daycoval currency exchange house.  They’ll take a digitized picture of the check to verify its authenticity.  Then they’ll notify you by phone to return.  You return to the exchange house, submit the check to be sent to Daycoval’s main office to be cashed.  Daycoval will then deposit the funds in your Brazilian bank account as a TED transfer.  The whole process takes at least 40 days.  Daycoval also charges a fee for the service equivalent to 10% the value of the check.